# ASP.NET.One of database table is not converted to entity data model?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have 3 tables in my database like this:

[image]

In my ASP.NET Mvc app. I use entity data model.
When I convert database to entity data model TBL_VOTES_ARTICLE table is not converted. Others are converted.

Why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: it has to do with a table structure not sure if it would cause a problem but might be join primary key

Comment: How can I change database desing? or Is it necessary?

Comment: what kind of Visual studio are you using?? I would try to rename the table TBL_VOTES_ARTICLE to TBL_VOTES_ARTICLE1 some time it helps if not you have to go to sql server manager I would try to add a new primary key  TBL_VOTES_ARTICLEID make it identity and remove primary key from two other fields

Comment: Yes. It works. You should write the last comment as answers. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what kind of Visual studio are you using??

I would try to rename the table TBL_VOTES_ARTICLE to TBL_VOTES_ARTICLE1 some time it helps if not you have to go to sql server manager I would try to add a new primary key TBL_VOTES_ARTICLEID make it identity and remove primary key from two other fields